# Javascript string/object/array confusion with JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object

I'm having a Laravel backend return some errors via Validator. These errors are passed through a HTTP response made by angular, and returned in JSON format.

The object is structured as seen below:

[image]

That `name` object has a value, which is the actual message that I'm after.

Currently, using loops etc., I can only get the name of the array (`name`) as a string...

**I sometimes get multiple arrays within this error object, and I won't always know their names, so how may I retrieve that 0-index value in each of them, in a loop?**

Thanks for any help.

---

Edit #1

Looping through it like this:

```
for(var err in res.data.errors){
    console.log(Object.err[0][0]);
}
```

Gives me a `Cannot get [0] index of undefined`

Comment: Can't you get it using, during the loop, index 0? something like `Object.specificitem[index][0]`?

Comment: Edited, doesn't work for me either, thanks

Comment: Oh, i missunderstanded that, i think you are refering only one level index, this can help: `for (var index in Object) { Object[index][0] }`

Comment: This worked, thank you Diego

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
let errors = Object.values(response.data.errors);
// errors is now an array of arrays containing the validation errors
errors.forEach( (errorArray) => {
  console.log(errorArray[0]);
} );
```

Another approach would be using `Object.keys()` instead of values. This is similar to what you already tried, where you get the name of the error property as a string, and then use it to access each error array:

```
let keys = Object.keys(response.data.errors);
keys.forEach( (errorKey) => {
  console.log('error type', errorKey);
  let errorArray = response.data.errors[errorKey];
  console.log(errorArray[0]);
} );
```